# Laptop and Tablet

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am planning to travel from Canada to Nepal via India (dehli airport)? I am thinking to bring my one laptop and one tablet (surface RT). Now i would like to know if there is any custom tax or else. ?

Comment: Come on. Nepal is not Somalia. Of course, you can bring a laptop and a tablet with your carry on baggage. You can see people who have a laptop and a tablet at teh same time on every airplane. It's OK.

Comment: @Derfder - You'd be surprised. On the flight to Bolivia they hand you a paper saying you are allowed 2 cell phones and one camera plus one personal computing device. Of course, the lines are really blurred when going to Ecuador they say you can have one photo camera and one video camera while both nowadays capture either type of media.

Comment: @Itai Did you actually saw that they confiscated a tablet from somebody who had also a laptop? You didn't. End of story.

Comment: Thank you both. But my concerns were: "Will the Indian Custom Department make any issue or not?" Do they count Microsoft surface RT as a laptop or not?

Comment: @Amit - I did not see this in India but in Thailand I had to make a declaration of temporary import and show the items on when exiting. I assume that India would be concerned with the same thing, that you are entering with 2 but leaving with 1. Of course, with all those new devices, the lines are blurry and you may get a different reaction depending on which customs official you get.